# Error while trying to create a Laravel project - OpenSSL Error messages:Failed to enable crypto

Tags: laravel, openssl, composer-php

I've been struggling to create a Laravel project for hours, I've searched a lot and I couldn't figure out a solution for this problem. I hope someone had the same problem before or know how can I solve this.

Here we go:

I'm trying to create a simple project in composer through this command:

```
  laravel new blog
```

And also tried this one:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog



And I'm getting this error:

$ laravel new blog --force
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 67 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.1): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
```

> Failed to download erusev/parsedown from dist: The
>   "https://api.github.com/repos/erusev/parsedown/zipball/92e9c27ba0e74b8b028b111d1b6f956a15c01fc1"
>   file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages:

```
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you running vagrant or within some other vm environment?

Comment: No I am not running vagrant.

Comment: @CrisnaXtha were you able to fix this? For me I turned off the sslverify check, but everything is cloning from cache?